# How to override request id send to aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

AWS Api Gateway docs is crystal clear about the capacity of API Clients override de Request ID here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference

More specific on the $context.requestId description: "An ID for the request. Clients can override this request ID. Use $context.extendedRequestId for a unique request ID that API Gateway generates."

I'm trying to send an requestId to override the one generated inside Api Gateway, but i'm cant figure out how.

Any one knows hot to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by adding the same header to the ingoing request:

```
x-amzn-RequestId=ABC123
```

This will cause the `$context.requestId` to equal `ABC123`, and the `extendedRequestId` will be the shorter random char string value. There will not be a UUID type Id given.

Comment: I was testing the API on AWS Console, and it wasn't working with this header..... I changed to Postman and then it worked.. thanks....